Spring Boot Load Datasources from Table
I am trying to learn how to work with multiple Data Sources in Spring Boot.
I was able to use AbstractRoutingDataSource and load  Data Sources inside a Filter from the Table in the Database that contained username and password for each schema.
Full code is at https://github.com/ivoronline/springboot_db_multitenant_dingleentity_shcemaparamtersfromtable
Problem that I don't know how to solve is that while initializing AbstractRoutingDataSource I need to provide defaultDatabase but at this point I am still not able to load connenction parameters from the Database. Because if in MultiTenantConfig I try to use @Autowired TenantRepository tenantRepository; I get circular reference.
So first I need to create MultiTenantDataSource that extends AbstractRoutingDataSource with some default data source in order to be able to later populate it with actual useful datasources. I tried to define some fake datasource in the application.properties but then I get error " Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url'" if he is unable to connect to Schema.
Also the idea that if tenant doesn't exist he will save in default tenant doesn't make sense. Is it possible to prevent that somehow? I would rather have an Exception instead. Should I create some fake empty Schema with no Tables so that I get Exception when he tries to save something there?
MultiTenantConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  basePackages            = "com.ivoronline.multitenant.repository",
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "multiEntityManager",
  transactionManagerRef   = "multiTransactionManager"
)
public class MultiTenantConfig {

  //PROPERTIES
  public static Map<Object, Object>   targetDataSources     = new HashMap<>();
  public static MultiTenantDataSource multitenantDataSource = new MultiTenantDataSource();
  private final String ENTITY_PACKAGE = "com.ivoronline.multitenant.entity";
  
  //=========================================================================================================
  // DEFAULT DATA SOURCE
  //=========================================================================================================
  @Primary
  @Lazy
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("default.spring.datasource")
  public DataSource defaultDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
  }
  
  //=========================================================================================================
  // MULTI ROUTING DATA SOURCE
  //=========================================================================================================
  @Bean
  public MultiTenantDataSource multiRoutingDataSource() {
    
    multitenantDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource());
    multitenantDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

    return multitenantDataSource;
    
  }

